# Epic AppOrchard Tokens in OAuth2 Context Missing Value

Tags: oauth-2.0, hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I'm testing my SMART application on Epic AppOrchard using Hyperspace simulator. Currently facing issue related to Tokens in OAuth2 context. Following is my Token URL: mrn=%PATID%&user=%SYSLOGIN%&providerId=%USERPROVFHIRID%

I used to get providerId parameter filled with correct practitioner Id that I can use to fetch Practitioner information until start of third week of July 2019. Now I'm receiving empty string in providerId parameter. I don't think I've changed anything that made my application receive empty string in providerId.

Can someone please help me understand how these token parameters are filled with correct values and/or under what circumstances they remain empty?
Maybe a guide how Tokens in OAuth2 Context work could help. Thanks

Comment: Azaz - you might have better luck asking your App Orchard TS directly (if you have one), or asking on the [App Orchard Developer Forum](https://userweb.epic.com/AppOrchard) (which is actively monitored by AO TS).

Comment: Thanks @Cooper, sure will do.

Comment: I was wondering why devs don't share common questions/solution related to SMART and FHIR here on SO. Instead, I see google groups where most of the discussion is taken place.

Comment: For SMART and FHIR in general, SO may be fine, especially for questions around libraries and such.  But for a lot of the App Orchard SMART issues, those are just configuration issues, and not really programming related.  If other devs have answers, great, we don't *object* to using SO - however our official support folks don't monitor SO regularly.

Comment: Sounds fair enough.